# Ionic 3: jumps whole app when scrolling screens

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an issue, when scrolling screen was jumping - the background appears blank white.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a **[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have **[tried so far](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**, and take the **[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but I think you want to disable the overscroll effect. Add the following to your `config.xml` as child element of the `<widget`> element:

```
 <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

You can find the related docs [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/config_ref/index.html#preference).

Comment: thanks for your answer. My question is: when I scroll, my app is scrolled as well as in the video I send.

Comment: Yes thats why you need to do what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @David..Sir,i have an issue realted to list is not scrolled in iphone7 only but in the another iphone it will work do u know why list not scrolled in the iphone7?

Answer (score 0):

So I also faced this issue but then too I didn't solve my problem in IONIC 3 iOS build.

> So you have to just go to Page html file and update -

```
<ion-content class="no-scroll">
```

> Then go to page scss file and update the css-

```
 .no-scroll {
    div.scroll-content {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
```

**This will work. Happy coding!!**

Answer (score 0):

In case of Ionic Vue

`<ion-content :force-overscroll="false">`

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content